# Send Message to Nearby Mobile Phone

Tags: flash, sms, message, detect, gsm

I have been given the task of sending messages (SMS/Flash/ other formats) to any phone entering a restricted area... How do I detect the phone and send message to it without any prior knowledge of it's SIM Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rely on GSM technology then you need a server-based solution. You need a mechanism for registering devices on the server. The server queries the mobile networks location center for device positions and send a message if a position trigger fires. Position information may be less accurate for this solution.

If you have the means to do nearfield communication, e.g. WiFi or Bluetooth, you could build a solution on top of this. You would mark the restricted zone with NFC technology and have software running on the device looking for these markers. If the device detects such a marker this would trigger an appropriate action, maybe ask the mobile network for a message.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time since the question was asked, but I think this link explains two ways this can be done:
[Someone Sent a Mysterious Mass Text to Protesters in Kiev](http://mashable.com/2014/01/21/kiev-protesters-text-message/)

It explains that you can use something called [IMSI catcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSI-catcher), or stingray. But I don't think they are legal to use. I don't know if there's any better/easier solution.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Throws a new light on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Standard GSM phones communicate their position unsolicited only when changing the location area. Usually a location area consist of a different number of single cells (in cities much more than in rural areas). So, basically you do not know where the phone is currently located within a location area except it is in use, it is logging in or after a specified time (depending on th eprovider). If called, all cells will query until the phone reveals its current position. So, you would have to force the phone to log in again (neither nice nor legal) or call it/send an SMS (but you don't know the number). Smart phones are easier in this context because the communicate a lot if you do not switch of some "features".

But, you would have to work somehow for mobile phone providers and have access to their servers. So, you would have access to SIM data anyway. So, the task you were given is quite unusual...